# how do I calculate the remaining time left from a given unix formated data before the day in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I have two Unix timestamp data(I am getting from client side)

```
 const orgStartTime = 1603801800;  // Tue Oct 27 2020 23:00:00 GMT+1030 (Australian Central Daylight Time)
 const orgEndTime = 1603807200; // Wed Oct 28 2020 00:30:00 GMT+1030 (Australian Central Daylight Time)
```

output: I'm trying to calculate the usage Time for a each day
so,  `orgStartTime =  1603801800` the day will finish in 1 hours( needs to store the this value "Tue Oct 27 2020"). Then, I will to calculate the rest of the time to put on the next day(inMinutes).

```
output should look this: 
1. StrtTime = 1603801800;
   EndTime = 1603722540; 
   usageTime: 59(minutes)
2. StrtTime = 1603805400;
   EndTime = 1603807200;
   usageTime: 30(minutes)
```

question : what if the endTime is after 2days? in that case I need to generate 3 orgStartTime and orgEndTime

think this problem as more like screenTime application

Thanks in advance

open to use any library if I have to fulfill this requirement

Comment: What happend to the one minute between 2020-10-27T23:59:00 and 2020-10-28T00:00:00

Comment: I am going to still calculate it, Its just the above taken unix timestamp is till "2020-10-27T23:59:00 and 2020-10-28T00:00:00" for this time only! In other words feel free to add the left minute on then 1st output ``` usageTime = 60 mins ```

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with the brute force way..

idea is==>

1. we find the difference between the startUnix and endUnix given from
   the client side.(difference time)
2. we run the loop till the difference time.
3. we keep increasing the time and checking whether the day has been changed or not. if changed store the result else keep increase.

```
  let futureDate;
  let tempNewDate = startTime;
  let storeAllMinute = 0;
  let getTempMinutes =0;
  // getting day from json start time
  let getDayFromStartTimeJson = getStartTimeArray[0];
  // console.log(getDayFromStartTimeJson);
  // future date
  let futureDateArray = [];
  let futureDateHoursArray = [];
  let count = 1;
  let prevDate =0;
  let prevDatefuture;
  let getDifferenceInMinutes = Math.floor((endTime - startTime)/60);



  for (let index = 1; index <= getDifferenceInMinutes; index++) {
    // step 1: start increasing the time in minute
    let temp = 1*60;
    storeAllMinute = temp + storeAllMinute;
    getTempMinutes = Math.floor(temp/60) + getTempMinutes; // get the minutes for while loop
    prevDate = tempNewDate;
    tempNewDate = startTime + storeAllMinute; // getting the newDate
    futureDate = new Date(tempNewDate*1000).toLocaleString("en-AU", {timeZone: "Australia/Adelaide"});
    prevDatefuture = new Date(prevDate*1000).toLocaleString("en-AU", {timeZone: "Australia/Adelaide"});
    let prevDateArray = prevDatefuture.split("/");

    console.log("current"+ futureDate + "prev" + prevDatefuture);
    futureDateArray = futureDate.split("/");
    futureDateHoursArray = futureDate.split(":");
    console.log(prevDateArray[0]);
    console.log(futureDateArray[0]);
    if (prevDateArray[0] != futureDateArray[0]) {
      console.log("sasaa");
    }
    // now we are also check if the day has start changed
    // checking date, hours and minute from future date and enddate JSON
    if (futureDateArray[0] == getEndTimeArray[0] && futureDateHoursArray[1] == getEndHoursArray[1] &&
       futureDateHoursArray[2] == getEndHoursArray[2] ) {
      console.log("runned");
      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("users/" + data.body.userId + "/usages")
          .doc(endTime.toString())
          .set({
            inMinutes: getTempMinutes,
            endTime: endTime,
          });
    }
    if (prevDateArray[0] != futureDateArray[0]) { // now checking if the date has changed its not equal to endDate time
      // then create a new collection
      console.log("2n loop runned");
      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("users/" + data.body.userId + "/usages")
          .doc(`${tempNewDate}`)
          .set({
            inMinutes: getTempMinutes,
            endTime: tempNewDate,
          });
      getTempMinutes = 0;
    }
    //
    count ++;
    // console.log(getTempMinutes); // displaying the minutes
  }
```